# Load webapp from the compiled jar file with embedded Tomcat 7

Tags: jsp, web-applications, executable-jar, embedded-tomcat-7

I usually develop web application using embedded jetty server and wrap them in .exe file using applications like Launcher4j. I like to put my web application folder inside a java package and read it from there instead of putting it in a folder next to the generated .exe file. I like to do so to protect my webapp from being edited. With an embedded jetty server it is done like this:

```
String jetty_home = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(webappsClassPath).toExternalForm();
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setServer(server);
    webapp.setContextPath(contextPath);
    webapp.setResourceBase(jetty_home + "/webapps/MyWebapp");
    webapp.setWar(webappsFolder);
    webapp.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
```

How can I manage the same with an  embedded Tomcat 7 or Tomcat 8-alpha server?
Thank you! :)

Comment: I had a similar thought but was never able to implement it. Your code cleared my doubt (regarding jetty), thanks.

Comment: @coding_idiot Well, I kind of got this crazy idea of a way to implement it. A memory file system could be created and the webapp files could be copies from the jar packages to the the memory file system and read from there. I have no idea if it is possible for tomcat to read from such a thing. At the moment, it is just a wild idea but I'm going to implement it and see how it turns out. If anyone has ideas about that possible soulution or any others, please share :). I'm going to ry and implement the memory file system using java's nio tonight.

Comment: Any update about it? I'm also trying to do the same with Tomcat8, but no success. I have spent quite long time on that so I'll just move to Jetty because I need to get it working and the server itself doesn't matter.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it :) I just extracted the files in a temporary directory. Not really a fix but managed to deliver on time :D